# Updating object doesn't work properly in Hibernate 3

Tags: insert-update, hibernate3

**Pojo object:**

```
public class Test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    @Column(columnDefinition="int default 100")
    private int number; 
    .....getter and setter........
}
```

**Backend Action:**

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value= "/common/index3")
public String index3(){

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Test t = session.get(Test.class, 1);

    t.setNumber(t.getNumber() - 1);

    System.out.println("invoked");

    session.update(t);

    return "success";
}
```

**Web page ajax trigger**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
        $.post("/common/index3");
    }
}
```

**issue**

from client side I sent 3 times requests to backend action, and the action was invoked properly 3 times as well, however, in database the 'Number' column only was deducted 1 time, after invoked 3 times, column value become from 100 to 99, I don't know why it was only deducted 1 time, the expected value should be 97, I tried to flush & clear session to avoid the hibernate3 cache issue, anybody know how to solve this?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your transactions aren't being committed to the database. You should use transactions while communicating with the DB.

After starting your session, start the transaction with

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()
```

and after completing your queries, commit them to the DB with a `tx.commit()`.

Comment: I think I found the problem, as you said, the problem happens while the previous transaction is not commit yet, so that if there are more requesting come, those requesting possibly been cancelled, I tried add an OPTIMISTIC locker, it did throw exceptions like transaction has not been completed yet..., now to solve this I use ajax send all the numbers to backend in one time, then handle there, no problem so far.